# Submit Form dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, form-submit

I am using a dropdown plugin called [dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/), which replaces select menus with better looking, custom dropdowns. I want to display my list of WordPress categories in this dropdown. Here is the PHP code that generates the dropdown:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get" class="pretty">
    <?php $select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0');
    echo $select; ?>
</form>
```

The JavaScript code to turn this into a "pretty dropdown" is as follows.

```
$('.pretty select').dropkick({
      theme: 'default',
      change: function (value, label) {
         INSERT CALLBACK HERE
      }
});
```

I need to write a callback that will submit the form after the user selects a category. How would I go about this?

I tried using `return this.form.submit()` and also `return $(this).parent().form.submit()` but that did not submit the form. How can I auto submit a form using jQuery?

The form action and method are already defined in the form.

Comment: Please see this other similar question for wordpress archive dropdowns and dropkick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487431/submit-wordpress-form-dropdown-with-jquery-onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to post the form.

Given that you only have one form in the DOM with the class `pretty`, you could post the form like this:

```
$("form.pretty").submit();
```

Comment: wow, didnt expect it to be that easy. Incredibly useful. Thanks!

Comment: To make things easier it would probably be best to use Nick George's version which searches for the form that "this" (the control) belongs to. In the long run it will make code re-use possible so you don't have to tell it which form (by class or by id), it just searches by parent.

Comment: I have another very similar question that I will post up in a minute. I will post the link here. If you dont mind taking a look your expertise could be of help! Just a moment

Comment: Here is the other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487431/submit-wordpress-form-dropdown-with-jquery-onchange

Comment: @JCHASE11 Happy it helped, and as mentioned by the others, if you have more than one form on the page then have a look at Nick's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Christofer Eliasson's answer may be correct, but just in case you have more than one form, this would be better:

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```